# CSS Div Element Functions Only When It Has a Border

Tags: html, css

I am designing a site for a new foundation, and I have set April 15 as my deadline for finishing it.  It is ready except for editing the content and fine-tuning the design.  In the fine-tuning, I am wrestling with an irksome little problem that I would like to ask someone to please help me solve.  The problem is simply this: a division in the site's structure will not function as I would like for it to function unless it has a border around it. Never seen a thing so erratic before.

The problem appears to be related to how the elements interact in the layout.  First, there is the html tag which holds the background image, a jpeg of a creek with some buildings on the far side and a green grove of grass created by a divisional tag (#greengrass) positioned at the bottom of the background image .  div#greengrass is styled to extend downward as a content div, resting on top of it, lengthens. It is this #greengrass element that performs awkwardly unless there is a border laced around it.

Specifically, if its border is removed, it projects upward and covers the background image, even though positioned to start where the background image ends. Its upward projection, therefore, makes the entire page background green.  But when it has a border, the background image of the creek shines through as bright as the sunny spring sun.

Thus, I have one question:  Why does the absence or presence of the division's border affect its behavior? Here is the url to the test site for the foundation: http://postmaterial.org/tests/signin-ap.php. At top center, I've added a link that lets you toggle between the bordered and borderless div#greengrass effects.  I have no clue as to the reason for the tag's behavior and would appreciate an explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: "Why does the absence or presence of the division's border affect its behavior?" I agree with ichao (as his answer stated) that collapsing margins is the issue.

However, I think the solution is to keep only a `border-top: 1px solid #009900` as it is only the top border that is needed to prevent the margin collapse. This will prevent the horizontal scroll bar from showing up.

Comment: Scott, I've made the change you suggested -- an extraordinary suggestion I must say.  Before my post, I had not been familiar with the concept of collapsing margins.  In relating this concept to horizontal scrolling, you've helped me improve my site's appearance remarkably. As for @Ichao's, I'm grateful for your support.

Answer (score 0):

without the border of #greengrass, the negative margin-top of its child collapses through (and pulls the entire construct out of sight, topwards), and in consequence, #greengrass is not pushed down enough by top anymore.

border prevents collapsing margins, as display:inline-block or display:table or float:left would in this case (overflow:hidden is not an option here). In old IE, any haslayout trigger like zoom:1 should do. I did not test it, though.

Comment: Ichao, this is fascinatingly interesting.  Also, the speed of your response is commendable.  All the while I had assumed borders to be solely aesthetic in function. You've changed this assumption, logically and conceptually. I am grateful for your help.